# Do I need an SSL certificate when using Paypal IPN on my site?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

The user enters their name/ address & billing information while on the paypal site. I only ask them to tell me if they are a vegetarian on my site, before directing them to paypal to pay. Once they have paid, the site  displays that they have paid in the admin area of your site, so it is obviously taking information from paypal for this - but not their debit/credit card details. Name, address etc.

Do I need an SSL certificate? I'm using shared hosting so what is the best option if I do need one? Thanks!

So I am only sending vegetarian yes or no. As I understand the paypal IPN in sending the person's names, address etc back to my site so that a list of people who have paid can be viewed in the admin area (not debit/credit card info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not collecting credit/debit card info on your site, then no... you don't need SSL.  It sounds like you are sending people to PayPal, who collects payment information, and PayPal then sends the user back to your site.  If this is so... you don't need SSL.

Comment: After the customer has paid at PayPal.com, PayPal then sends the person's address and name back to my site. No debit/ credit card information is sent though. Just before the customer is sent to PayPal, they say if they would prefer vegetarian/ non vegetarian food, this information is sent to PayPal before they pay